# Convergence in Expectation of $X_n = \sqrt{n} \mathbb{1}_{(1/n,2/n)}$

Tags: probability-theory

I would like to prove/disprove convergence in Expectation/$L^2$ of $X_n = \sqrt{n} \mathbb{1}_{(1/n,2/n)}$. The probability measure used is the lebesgue-measure on $[0,1]$.

$X_n$ converges in $L^2$ against X if and only if $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}E(|X_n-X|^2)=0$

So far I only came across questions asking to prove convergence against **specific** $X$ but I do not know what to do in this case. **(I don't want to use proof of a stronger type of convergence)**

---

I tried constructing several RVs that it could converge against but it did not work out. 
Also, I have shown that 
$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} E[|X_n|^2]=1$, but does that tell me anything about proving or disproving its $L^2$-convergence?
Surely, it does not converge against 0 in $L^2$ but how would I find/construct a RV that it converges against?

---

My answer would be that $X_n$ converges in $L^2$ (but the limit in $L^2$ is/can be ambiguous).

Comment: Can you find a limit of convergence in probability? If so, it's only possibility to be a limit in L^p

Comment: Yes, the limit for convergence in probability is 0. If that is indeed the only possibility (I have to think about that) then the answer is that it does not converge in $L^2$.

Comment: Do you already know that convergence in L^p implies conv. in probability? (Yes, it does not converge in L^2, but in L^1 it converges)

Comment: Yes, I know that already. Ah, now I see it... Ofc it need to have the same limit as in p. Thanks!